# Debian Oracle OSS Group key list expired

Tags: linux, debian, apt

I have a debian server running 8.8
When I do a simple sudo apt-get update I obtain the following :

```
Ign http://mirrors.online.net jessie InRelease
Hit http://mirrors.online.net jessie Release.gpg                                                                                                          
Hit http://mirrors.online.net jessie Release                                                                                                              
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease                                                                                                   
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie InRelease                                                                                                             
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie Release.gpg                                                                                                           
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie Release                                                    
Get:1 http://mirrors.online.net jessie/main Sources [7,055 kB]              
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/non-free Sources                                                                   
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/non-free amd64 Packages                                  
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main amd64 Packages                                                               
  404  Not Found
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/non-free Translation-en            
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main Translation-en_US                                                                  
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main Sources                                             
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main Translation-en                                                              
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/contrib Sources                                                        
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages                                   
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/contrib amd64 Packages                                
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/contrib Translation-en                                
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main Translation-en                                   
Get:2 http://mirrors.online.net jessie/non-free Sources [99.5 kB]              
Get:3 http://mirrors.online.net jessie/contrib Sources [50.8 kB]                 
Get:4 http://mirrors.online.net jessie/main amd64 Packages [6,790 kB]
Get:5 http://mirrors.online.net jessie/non-free amd64 Packages [83.6 kB]
Get:6 http://mirrors.online.net jessie/contrib amd64 Packages [50.2 kB]
Get:7 http://mirrors.online.net jessie/contrib Translation-en [38.5 kB]
Get:8 http://mirrors.online.net jessie/main Translation-en [4,583 kB]
Get:9 http://mirrors.online.net jessie/non-free Translation-en [72.1 kB]                    
Get:10 http://oss.oracle.com unstable InRelease [148 B]                               
Ign http://oss.oracle.com unstable InRelease                                     
Get:11 http://oss.oracle.com unstable Release.gpg [189 B]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Hit http://oss.oracle.com unstable Release                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Ign http://oss.oracle.com unstable Release                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Get:12 http://oss.oracle.com unstable/main amd64 Packages [148 B]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
Err http://oss.oracle.com unstable/main amd64 Packages                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

Get:13 http://oss.oracle.com unstable/non-free amd64 Packages [148 B]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
Err http://oss.oracle.com unstable/non-free amd64 Packages                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

Get:14 http://oss.oracle.com unstable/main Translation-en_US [148 B]
Get:15 http://oss.oracle.com unstable/main Translation-en [148 B]
Get:16 http://oss.oracle.com unstable/non-free Translation-en_US [148 B]
Get:17 http://oss.oracle.com unstable/non-free Translation-en [148 B]
Get:18 http://oss.oracle.com unstable/main amd64 Packages [148 B]
Err http://oss.oracle.com unstable/main amd64 Packages

Get:19 http://oss.oracle.com unstable/non-free amd64 Packages [148 B]
Err http://oss.oracle.com unstable/non-free amd64 Packages

Get:20 http://oss.oracle.com unstable/main Translation-en_US [148 B]
Get:21 http://oss.oracle.com unstable/main Translation-en [148 B]
Get:22 http://oss.oracle.com unstable/non-free Translation-en_US [148 B]
Get:23 http://oss.oracle.com unstable/non-free Translation-en [148 B]
Get:24 http://oss.oracle.com unstable/main amd64 Packages [148 B]
Err http://oss.oracle.com unstable/main amd64 Packages

Get:25 http://oss.oracle.com unstable/non-free amd64 Packages [148 B]
Err http://oss.oracle.com unstable/non-free amd64 Packages

Get:26 http://oss.oracle.com unstable/main Translation-en_US [148 B]
Get:27 http://oss.oracle.com unstable/main Translation-en [148 B]
Get:28 http://oss.oracle.com unstable/non-free Translation-en_US [148 B]
Get:29 http://oss.oracle.com unstable/non-free Translation-en [148 B]
Get:30 http://oss.oracle.com unstable/main amd64 Packages [148 B]
Get:31 http://oss.oracle.com unstable/non-free amd64 Packages [148 B]
Err http://oss.oracle.com unstable/non-free amd64 Packages

Get:32 http://oss.oracle.com unstable/main Translation-en_US [148 B]
Get:33 http://oss.oracle.com unstable/main Translation-en [148 B]
Get:34 http://oss.oracle.com unstable/non-free Translation-en_US [148 B]
Get:35 http://oss.oracle.com unstable/non-free Translation-en [148 B]
Get:36 http://oss.oracle.com unstable/main amd64 Packages [148 B]
Err http://oss.oracle.com unstable/main amd64 Packages
  HttpError404
Get:37 http://oss.oracle.com unstable/non-free amd64 Packages [148 B]
Err http://oss.oracle.com unstable/non-free amd64 Packages
  HttpError404
Get:38 http://oss.oracle.com unstable/main Translation-en_US [148 B]
Ign http://oss.oracle.com unstable/main Translation-en_US
Get:39 http://oss.oracle.com unstable/main Translation-en [148 B]
Ign http://oss.oracle.com unstable/main Translation-en
Get:40 http://oss.oracle.com unstable/non-free Translation-en_US [148 B]
Ign http://oss.oracle.com unstable/non-free Translation-en_US
Get:41 http://oss.oracle.com unstable/non-free Translation-en [148 B]
Ign http://oss.oracle.com unstable/non-free Translation-en                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Fetched 18.8 MB in 24s (761 kB/s)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
W: GPG error: http://oss.oracle.com unstable Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1378511808 KEYEXPIRED 1378511808 KEYEXPIRED 1378511808
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/bitcoin/bitcoin/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://oss.oracle.com/debian/dists/unstable/main/binary-amd64/Packages  HttpError404

W: Failed to fetch http://oss.oracle.com/debian/dists/unstable/non-free/binary-amd64/Packages  HttpError404

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Here is the output of sudo apt-key list :

```
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg
--------------------
pub   1024D/B38A8516 2006-09-05 [expired: 2013-09-06]
uid                  Oracle OSS group (Open Source Software group) <build@oss.oracle.com>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/bitcoin-bitcoin.gpg
------------------------------------------
pub   1024R/8842CE5E 2011-10-26
uid                  Launchpad PPA for Bitcoin

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-jessie-automatic.gpg
----------------------------------------------------------
pub   4096R/2B90D010 2014-11-21 [expires: 2022-11-19]
uid                  Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (8/jessie) <ftpmaster@debian.org>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-jessie-security-automatic.gpg
-------------------------------------------------------------------
pub   4096R/C857C906 2014-11-21 [expires: 2022-11-19]
uid                  Debian Security Archive Automatic Signing Key (8/jessie) <ftpmaster@debian.org>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-jessie-stable.gpg
-------------------------------------------------------
pub   4096R/518E17E1 2013-08-17 [expires: 2021-08-15]
uid                  Jessie Stable Release Key <debian-release@lists.debian.org>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-squeeze-automatic.gpg
-----------------------------------------------------------
pub   4096R/473041FA 2010-08-27 [expires: 2018-03-05]
uid                  Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (6.0/squeeze) <ftpmaster@debian.org>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-squeeze-stable.gpg
--------------------------------------------------------
pub   4096R/B98321F9 2010-08-07 [expires: 2017-08-05]
uid                  Squeeze Stable Release Key <debian-release@lists.debian.org>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-wheezy-automatic.gpg
----------------------------------------------------------
pub   4096R/46925553 2012-04-27 [expires: 2020-04-25]
uid                  Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (7.0/wheezy) <ftpmaster@debian.org>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-wheezy-stable.gpg
-------------------------------------------------------
pub   4096R/65FFB764 2012-05-08 [expires: 2019-05-07]
uid                  Wheezy Stable Release Key <debian-release@lists.debian.org>
```

We can clearly see that key B38A8516 is expired.
I have tried this command without succes :

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys B38A8516
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.66fa6TtioE --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/bitcoin-bitcoin.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-jessie-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-jessie-security-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-jessie-stable.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-squeeze-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-squeeze-stable.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-wheezy-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-wheezy-stable.gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys B38A8516
gpg: requesting key B38A8516 from hkp server pgp.mit.edu
gpg: key B38A8516: "Oracle OSS group (Open Source Software group) <build@oss.oracle.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
```

I have even tried to remove the key manually with apt-key del B38A8516 and reinstall it. I always end with the same expired keys...

Anyone have a hint on this ? I'm completly lost...

Cheers,
Astrus